# jQuery, sort table columns with colspan by clicking on the header

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, html-table

I'd like to sort a table using jQuery. The table has rows with 4 columns and  rows (which are displayed upon clicking on the preceeding 4 column one) with 1 column. Is it possible to sort the table by values of the 4 column rows? So e. g. after clicking Header 2 the table will be reversed assuming 1st click does ascending sort.

```
<table>
<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th><th>Header 4</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>XYZ</td><td>456</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr class="inside"><td colspan="4">Inside text</td></tr>
<tr><td>859</td><td>IOI</td><td>132</td><td>9</td></tr>
<tr class="inside"><td colspan="4">Inside text</td></tr>
<tr class="inside"><td colspan="4">Another inside text</td></tr>
<tr><td>798</td><td>GJOI</td><td>798</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr class="inside"><td colspan="4">Inside text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this jquery plugin meets your requirement pretty well.

[click here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin:

```js
$(function () {
  $("table").tablesorter();
});
```

```css
table.tablesorter {
  font-family:arial;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  margin:10px 0pt 15px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
  background-color: #e6EEEE;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  font-size: 8pt;
  padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
  background-image: url(bg.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td {
  color: #3D3D3D;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
  background-color:#F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
  background-image: url(asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
  background-image: url(desc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
  background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.26.6/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>XYZ</td>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inside">
        <td colspan="4">Inside text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>859</td>
        <td>IOI</td>
        <td>132</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inside">
        <td colspan="4">Inside text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inside">
        <td colspan="4">Another inside text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>798</td>
        <td>GJOI</td>
        <td>798</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inside">
        <td colspan="4">Inside text</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks good, however I'd like to have the Inside text rows kept under the corresponding main rows as before sorting